# Why do all the strategies I run show buy and sell 1 or 2 bars after the signal is generated

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wrote a strategy which showed a pretty good success rate, but when I looked at the trading panel, I noticed all the paper buy and sell orders take place 1 or 2 bars after the signal that generates them. Now I could understand that on a 3 or 15 minute chart, perhaps there is a lag, but this happens on daily, weekly even monthly charts. I have ran a couple of strategies that I found on the community scripts and the same thing happens. I have live data on my charts, so that is not the problem. Is this normal behavior for strategy testing. If so it gives very inaccurate results for the strategy as there are substantial price movements between some bars. Is it possible to correct that?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to use colors from another indicator.
Using `input.source()` operator, you can use only the values of the series, which are output as graphs (by `plot*` operators).

Comment: Sorry. This was the answer to another question.